# image and data is not showing adjacent in bootstrap3

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to image and its relevant data in bootstrap. For that I am writing code like below

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align=center>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
               <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                   <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" src="img/uthappizza.png" alt="Uthappiza">
                        </a>
                     <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">Uthappizza</h2>
                        <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and
                          Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine
                          cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and
                          Buffalo Paneer.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#">More &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
```

I am getting output like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saoB7.png)

I want it to be side by side I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pull-left` to your image as a class. [Bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/hviZlov0eY)

Comment: Hey thanks that's worked..one que I have similar kind of code with different image for that it was showing properly. Can u suggest why for this snippet it dint work?

Comment: @lomeshshah You're welcome and without seeing your other code I couldn't tell you.  It could be a number of different reasons.  Can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: Sorry I can't as I have reputation less than 15.If i paste my code can u tell me??